# How to interpret a conditional smooths plot of a splines model?

Tags: r, regression, interpretation, splines

**Let's have simulated data**

*higher weight should be associated with lower height in this data*

```
df1 = data.frame(weight = rnorm(500, 20, 5), height = rnorm(500, 180, 15))
df2 = data.frame(weight = rnorm(500, 60, 15), height = rnorm(500, 140, 15))
df_final = rbind(df1, df2)
```

**Model**

*I use lognormal model since my original data requires it.*

```
m = brm(height ~ s(weight), data = df_final, family = lognormal())
```

*Model done with brms package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/index.html*

**Conditional smooths plot**

```
conditional_smooths(m, effects = "weight")
```

[image]

*conditional_smooths() function: https://rdrr.io/cran/brms/man/conditional_smooths.brmsfit.html*

**Question**

Why y-axis is not in the original y-variable scale. How to read this? What's "mu"? How should I interpret the plot in a meaningful way?

Or is it so that the conditional_smooths() function does not transform posterior back the y-variable scale? In this simulated data case, conditional_effects() gives a nice plot on the original y-scale. **However, conditional_effects() and conditional_smooths() plots differ while using my real data! Conditional_effects plot has much-much wider CI-s.**

Comment: Is this `brm` from CRAN package `brms`? Please include such important information (and , do it as an edit, not only comment!). We also need detais of your simulated example!

Comment: Also include the details of how you made this plot.

Comment: Good points! Added simulated data, full model, web links for functions, new plot on simulated data. Lognormal model is the only good option I can use with my original data.